# How can I get java and neo4j to work in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, neo4j

I am using mint 17.2 and have neo4j 3.06 Comunity Edition it is running fine on localhost:7474.

I wish to program in Java 1.08, using Eclipse Mars 2 but I cannot get it to work.

I am using a maven project and have the following  in my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.geekcap.informit</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-sample-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>neo4j-sample-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have the following in my app.java file

```
package com.geekcap.informit.neo4j_sample_app;


import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;

public class App 
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
      Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7474", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
      Session session = driver.session();

      session.run("CREATE (a:Person {name:'Arthur', title:'King'})" );

      StatementResult result = 
          session.run("Match (a:Person) WHERE a.name = 'Arthur' RETURN a.name AS name, a.title AS title");
      while (result.hasNext()) {
        Record record = result.next();
        System.out.println(record.get("title").asString() + " " + 
            record.get("name").asString());
      }

      session.close();
      driver.close();
    }
```

I get the following error when I try to run it as a java application.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to process request: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:87)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:63)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:52)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.allocate(InternalConnectionPool.java:191)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool$1.allocate(InternalConnectionPool.java:180)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.allocate(ThreadCachingPool.java:212)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquireFromGlobal(ThreadCachingPool.java:164)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.ThreadCachingPool.acquire(ThreadCachingPool.java:118)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.pool.InternalConnectionPool.acquire(InternalConnectionPool.java:109)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalDriver.session(InternalDriver.java:53)
  at com.geekcap.informit.neo4j_sample_app.App.main(App.java:12)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
  at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(EngineInputRecord.java:156)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:868)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
  at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.unwrap(TLSSocketChannel.java:186)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.runHandshake(TLSSocketChannel.java:127)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.<init>(TLSSocketChannel.java:95)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.<init>(TLSSocketChannel.java:77)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.TLSSocketChannel.<init>(TLSSocketChannel.java:70)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient$ChannelFactory.create(SocketClient.java:235)
  at org.neo4j.driver.internal.connector.socket.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:74)
  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 10):

The `7474` port is the HTTP port. Since you're using the `bolt://` protocol, you should connect to the `7687` port. Or actually remove the port since it's the default value:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
```

Also make sure that the Bolt protocol is actually active on the Neo4j instance, by uncommenting in `conf/neo4j.conf` (remove the preceding `#`):

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

or at least, to limit to local connections:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=127.0.0.1:7687
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Frank. I tried the above and it still does not work. I used port 7474 because I can access browser via that port.

Comment: My bet is that the protocol is not active, and the error message and stack trace are slightly different. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Tried removing # from dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687 it still fails but the fault has changed too: Unable to process request: General SSLEngine problem

Answer (score 0):

SSL Errors suggest that the client is expecting encrypted channel, but the server is not encrypted (hence the plaintext connection message in the exception stack trace).

Looking over the Neo4j manual, you might want to look into the following section to see how to configure the client and / or server for either encrypted or 'clear-text':

- https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/#driver-authentication-encryption
- http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/#bolt-connector

You can disable SSL (obviously not recommended in production, but useful to diagnose if this is your issue) on the bolt channel by setting the following in your neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED
```

And then restart your neo4j instance

Comment: Thank you for your reply Chris. I tried setting dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=DISABLED it was OPTIONAL but it still failed, I also tried put a third parameter in the GraphDatabase.driver to make it GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost, AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"), Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig());